# Did Tyler Durden diegetically hijack someones car?

Tags: plot-explanation, fight-club

When the Narrator in *Fight Club* is done struggling to retrieve his luggage at the airport, he sees Tyler hop into a red convertible with the car's owner yelling the following.

> "Hey! That's my car!"

Is the car's owner just another part of the Narrator's imagination?

Comment: I'm not sure 'diegetically' is the correct word for what you are describing, since even if it is imaginary/hallucinatory it is still part of the narrative of the film's world, not something only the audience can see. I'm not sure what other word to use, though.

Comment: Either the carjacking or the narrator conversation with the airport employee was imaginary.  Hmmmm...interesting

Comment: @user7294900 if you haven't seen the film it would spoil it a bit to explain it to you. The actual question is verging on spoilerness.

Comment: @steelersquirrel Or they happened further apart in time than we see.

Comment: @steelersquirrel +1 yes, this. He suffers a humiliation at the hands of the airport employee which prompt a personality turn.